How do completely disable automatic system updates in Sequoia?
I have a macOS 15 system that, for development reasons, cannot be updated unless I explicitly choose to update it.
In previous versions of macOS, it was sufficient to just turn off automatic updates in System Settings / Preferences completely. However, now in Sequoia, it aggressively tries to force me to update even with every one of those settings turned off.
It presents me with this "Updates Available" notification:

There is no option not to install the update. This is infuriating, because not only has it taken away fundamental control of my own system, but it's essential that I not update this system!
What can I do to avoid the update? Even better, what can I do to prevent these notifications from ever appearing in the first place?

Which macOS 15 are you running? 15, 15.0x, 15.1, or 15.1.1?  Scratching for clues - this will be hard for us to diagnose because it's rare and that update may have already been routinely accepted. You might want to leave that notification on screen until you can get Apple support on the phone/chat. Someone here might be able to suggest how to disable the update internally in Sequoia - some plist probably references queued or pending updates, as a guess.

This is macOS 15.1. Presumably the update is for 15.1.1. I've never had the automatic update options turned on while the system had internet access, so I don't see how this update could have been already downloaded or accepted.

Is that the OS trying to install updates from the MAS, or is it trying to install an OS update?

It's an OS update

You don’t have to click the buttons in the notification you screenshotted. You can just swipe it away or click the X in the top left corner. The system won’t install anything without you choosing to.

In System Settings > General > Software Update, you can click on the little "information" icon to get a dialog with options.

If you turn off "download updates when available", then that should fix it.

I did turn all of those off, and it still showed me the notification!

As far as I have been able to find you will get the notification no matter what. I solved that by taking System Settings out of the dock and accessing it from the Apple menu. Not an  ideal situation but it removed the annoying, spurious, red dot.

How did you get a "Check for updates" checkbox? In 15.1.1 it is not there for me (the rest is identical).

TL;DR: Use host file to disable notification.
127.0.0.1  swdist.apple.com
127.0.0.1  swscan.apple.com
127.0.0.1  swcdn.apple.com
127.0.0.1  xp.apple.com
127.0.0.1  gdmf.apple.com
127.0.0.1  mesu.apple.com
127.0.0.1  updates.cdn-apple.com


I found the solution from sysin.org and tested it's worked on macOS 15.1.1（24B91)
Step to change hostfile

Open a terminal session. (Command+Space -> Spotlight -> terminal.app)
Paste the following commands into the terminal, it may need your password for the sudo permission to write content to system host.

sudo tee -a /etc/hosts <<EOF
127.0.0.1  swdist.apple.com
127.0.0.1  swscan.apple.com
127.0.0.1  swcdn.apple.com
127.0.0.1  xp.apple.com
127.0.0.1  gdmf.apple.com
127.0.0.1  mesu.apple.com
127.0.0.1  updates.cdn-apple.com
EOF


Enjoy your Mac without any update notifications!

Note: Remember to remove the contents from the host file if need to check/update the system.
